# WPF - Panel seems to load all item at once

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, virtualization

I want to show 2000 items with image (thumbnail).

If I use normal list view, it will consume about 2GB memory with UI virtualization. Therefore, I tried to handle this problem using Data Virtualization followed [https://github.com/lvaleriu/Virtualization]. The idea is to load only a page of items. When we scroll down until access more than half of a page, a new page is requested. Hence, only several pages are stored in the memory and the memory consumed is about 150MB.

All good until I want to display items in a grid view (like using wrap panel or uniform gird). The problem now is that all pages are requested at the beginning leading to 2GB memory used. I investigate a bit and the problem may lie on itemspanel. It tries to load all data to locate the item and that what's exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Does anyone meet similar problem? Can you help me figure it out?

Thank you in advanced

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
    <!-- Problem when I add this part-->
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <!-- End -->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="250"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="250">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Data.FullPath}" 
                    TextAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="auto"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Data.FullPath, Converter={local:FileToIconConverter}}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top" MaxHeight="200"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Data virtualization code can be found in [https://github.com/lvaleriu/Virtualization]. I won't post here since it is a bit complicated.

Comment: Please edit your question, and show us the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @Clemens I edited. Please check if it helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: WrapPanel does not support virtualization. You may search the web for something like a VirtualizingWrapPanel.

Comment: Instead of tweaking Panel's layout performance, you can define a special DataTemplate for your images, which consists of a wrapper user control, which binds to the URI of the image, i.e. the user control just knows how to get the image, but doesn't display it. Then you override the IsVisibleChanged event and (if I'm not wrong) it will fire when the item is brought in and out of view, so you should be able to load the image from the URI on demand.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the keyword. It works. However, I'm building a plugin so I want to minimize plugins used. Can you help any further on that?

Comment: @shadow32 thank you. I tried that way but a bit block on UI. I tried async command but still cause block.